# Duplicate events received from POCO DirectoryWatcher

Tags: c++, linux, poco-libraries

I'm trying to use the DirectoryWatcher class from POCO's file system library to monitor a specific folder for changes. The code is pretty simple and looks like this:

```
Monitor::Monitor() {
    pattern = new Glob("/path/to/dir/*.dat",
                       Glob::GLOB_DOT_SPECIAL);

    watcher = new DirectoryWatcher(std::string("/path/to/dir"));

    watcher->itemAdded += delegate(this, &Monitor::onFileAdded);
    watcher->itemModified += delegate(this, &Monitor::onFileChanged);
}

void Monitor::onFileAdded(const DirectoryWatcher::DirectoryEvent& addEvent) {
    if (pattern->match(addEvent.item.path())) {
        std::cout << "File added: " << addEvent.item.path() << std::endl;
    }
}

void Monitor::onFileChanged(const DirectoryWatcher::DirectoryEvent& changeEvent) {
    if (pattern->match(changeEvent.item.path())) {
        std::cout << "File changed: " << changeEvent.item.path() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I'm observing some odd behavior. If I copy a new version of a file over a file that's already in the watched folder, I receive the 'item changed' notification twice. If I open a file that's already in the watched folder, edit its contents and save it, I receive an 'item added' notification followed by an 'item changed' notification.

This is on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 and ext4 file system with POCO 1.4.6p2.

Has anyone else observed similar behavior? Could this be related to some specific characteristic of my machine and the OS/file system combo? Is it possible to filter the unwanted events somehow?

Thanks in advance.