# Poco::DirectoryWatcher does not handle network connection lost

Tags: windows, visual-c++, poco-libraries

Using Poco 1.10.1 for Windows, I tried the following code:

```
try
{
   Poco::DirectoryWatcher dw( "\\test"); getch();
}
catch( const Poco::Exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.displayText();
}
```

But if "\test" is deleted while *DirectoryWatcher()* is running, no exception is received.
Furthermore, if "\test" resides on a mapped drive and the network connection is lost and reestablished,
no more events are received from that moment on.

I´ve also tried to provide my own error handler through *Poco::ErrorHandler::set()* - but that changed nothing.

Any hints ? t

Answer (score 0):

There are some exceptions thrown and handled internal to the `DirectoryWatcher`.  You can be notified of these exceptions by registering for a delegate similar to the way you would for `itemAdded`.

See the base code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806725/duplicate-events-received-from-poco-directorywatcher).

Then you can add a scanError delegate

```
   watcher->scanError += Poco::delegate(this, &Monitor::onScanError);
```

and

```
   void onScanError(const Poco::Exception& exc) {
      std::cout << "Exc: " << exc.what() << std::endl;
   }
```

You will then be notified of a `Poco::FileAccessDeniedException` and a `Poco::PathNotFoundException`, respectively.